# how to give permission to zsh terminal in windows 10?

Tags: permissions, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have installed zsh with oh-my-zsh and my terminal is looking good.
but it does not have any permission to read and execute.
i want to make zsh as normal cmd, how to give permission to ZSH terminal?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you mean by "give permission to a terminal"? Describe in detail the behaviour you have right now, and the behaviour you want to have. Also describe which zsh implementation you have installed (i.e. Cygwin, WSL, or something else), and which terminal program you are using.

Comment: give permission to the terminal I mean. Whenever i do `cc prog1.c` it says `cc : permission denied`, it means my terminal does not have permission to execute or read certain files and can't do much with it, and with cmd `cc prog1.c` works mean cmd can read and execute the file.. its sort of like making zsh admin.

Comment: No, because your terminal is not a user and can not execute anything. Hence you can not give permissions to a terminal. The message means that you don't have permissions on either cc or prog1.c. What are the permissions of cc and prog1.c? It could be that it lacks read permissions for you.

Comment: no! I as a user have all the permission to read the file and execute and can do anything with cmd or PowerShell but can't do with ubuntu terminal. so do I need to attach the Ubuntu terminal to the user? I don't know what to do to allow the ubuntu terminal to have all the permission on windows 10. YES, I AM THE ADMIN OF MY PC.